Python 3.13 REPL key-binding ctrl+arrows not working
Previously when I ran py3.12 in shell I could use ctrl + left arrow or ctrl + right arrow to move one word back or forward (skip words).
Recently I've upgraded to py3.13 and it doesn't work anymore, how can I bring it back?
Note: when I run py3.12 using python -V:3.12 again it works so it seems to be related to py3.13 itself not the shell

Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and see [ask] if you want tips, but this is a great first question :)

It works fine for me using Gnome Terminal on Ubuntu with Python 3.13.1. What are you using?

I can confirm that this behaviour has changed, when running Python 3.13.1 on Windows. Ctrl+arrows navigates between word starts in 3.12 and previous versions, but not in 3.13. And this Reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1fybncq/python_313_released/ seems to suggest it is to do with this change https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/118840 - so a known issue, or even a conscious choice. The REPL isn't exactly a premier way to interact with Python anyway though.

@wjandrea Thank you for my first omment ;) I'm using windows 10 and Microsoft Terminal
